# CIVI-SA-2015-010: VERSION INFORMATION DISCLOSURE

Tags: security-advisory

The announcement of this security advisory (https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2015-010-version-information-disclosure) does not provide a patch that can be applied, and examining the CiviCRM git repository of the new versions (4.4.20, 4.6.10) the change(s) made are not apparent.

Can anyone shed light on the changes made for this security advisory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix for 4.6 is: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7101

Fix for 4.4 is: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7102

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the omission, I have updated the SA to show the relevant pull-requests, on which you can view the patches.